# Spring boot 1.2.5 Hibernate JPA nested many to many relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have 3 tables like following

Product {
    id,
    title
}

Product_image {
    product_id,
    image_type_id,
    path,
    alt_text
}

Product_image_type
{
    id, type_name
}

What I want the result object like this:

```
Product{
    id,
    title,
    image_types[
        {
             type_id,
             type_name,
             image [
                 {
                      alt_text,
                      path
                 },
                 {
                      alt_text,
                      path
                 }
             ] 
        },
        {
             type_id,
             type_name,
             image [
                 {
                      alt_text,
                      path
                 }
             ] 
        }
    ]
}
```

I did following

Product Class:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(
    name = "product_image",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "productId", referencedColumnName = "id") },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "typeId", referencedColumnName = "id") }
)   
private Set<ProductImageType> imageTypes = new HashSet();
```

Product_type_image class:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="imageTypes")
private Set<Product> products;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "productImageType")
private Set<ProductImage> productImages = new HashSet();
```

Product_image class:

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="productImage")
@JoinColumn(name="typeId", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private ProductImageType oneProductImageType;
```

I got kind of format like I want, however I got all product images for one type, I want only get the images for the product image only for current product. For example I asked for product_id = 1, I have 2 type , I want the images inside of these 2 type are only for product_id = 1.

The good example:

```
Prodcut{
    id: 1,
    title: "product title 1",
    image_types:[
    {
         type_id: 1
         type_name: "type example 1"
         image [
             {
                  product_id: 1,
                  alt_text: "something",
                  path: "http:something",
             },
             {
                  product_id: 1,
                  alt_text: "something2",
                  path: "http:something2",
             }
         ] 
    },
    {
         type_id: 2
         type_name: "type example 2"
         image [
             {
                  product_id: 1,
                  alt_text: "type 2 something",
                  path: "http:something",
             },
             {
                  product_id: 1,
                  alt_text: "type 2something2",
                  path: "http:something2",
             }
         ] 
    }
    ]
}
```

What I get now:

```
Prodcut{
    id: 1,
    title: "product title 1",
    image_types:[
    {
         type_id: 1
         type_name: "type example 1"
         image [
             {
                  product_id: 1,
                  alt_text: "something",
                  path: "http:something",
             },
             {
                  product_id: 1,
                  alt_text: "something2",
                  path: "http:something2",
             },
             {
                  product_id: 2,
                  alt_text: "something2",
                  path: "http:something2",
             },
             {
                  product_id: 3,
                  alt_text: "something2",
                  path: "http:something2",
             },
             {
                  product_id: 4,
                  alt_text: "something2",
                  path: "http:something2",
             },
             {
                  product_id: 4,
                  alt_text: "something2",
                  path: "http:something2",
             }
         ] 
    },
    {
         type_id: 2
         type_name: "type example 2"
         image [
             {
                  product_id: 1,
                  alt_text: "type 2 something",
                  path: "http:something",
             },
             {
                  product_id: 1,
                  alt_text: "type 2something2",
                  path: "http:something2",
             },
             {
                  product_id: 1,
                  alt_text: "something2",
                  path: "http:something2",
             },
             {
                  product_id: 2,
                  alt_text: "something2",
                  path: "http:something2",
             },
             {
                  product_id: 3,
                  alt_text: "something2",
                  path: "http:something2",
             },
             {
                  product_id: 4,
                  alt_text: "something2",
                  path: "http:something2",
             },
             {
                  product_id: 4,
                  alt_text: "something2",
                  path: "http:something2",
             }
         ] 
    }
    ]
}
```

Content in tables:

```
Product Table: 
    id    title
    1     product title 1
    2     product title 2
    3     product title 3
    4     product title 4
    5     product title 5

Product_image Table:
    product_id   image_type_id   path                alt_text
    1            1               http:something      something
    1            1               http:something2     something2
    1            2               http:something      type 2 something
    1            2               http:something2     type 2 something2
    2            1               http:something2     something2
    3            1               http:something2     something2
    4            1               http:something2     something2
    4            1               http:something2     something2
    2            2               http:something2     something2
    3            2               http:something2     something2
    4            2               http:something2     something2
    4            2               http:something2     something2

Product_image_type Table:
    id  type_name
    1   type example 1
    2   type example 2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the content of the different tables?

Comment: @CorneilduPlessis  I have updated the question with the content which associated with the sample data I posted. Please help me out thanks in advance

Comment: I would have thought that product_id,image_type_id would be unique index. If you enable output of sql and have a look at the queries produced it will help finding the problem.

Comment: @CorneilduPlessis but it is not unique this was the original design problem, I have to build my stuff on top of it.

Comment: The ids being in the same range may be confusing things. The join and inverse colums may be the wrong way round.

Comment: @CorneilduPlessis can you show me the right way to do it please ?

Comment: Do you have a small test project?

Comment: @CorneilduPlessis the code is in the question I do not know where to put small project

Comment: You can put a project on github or publicly share a zip from dropbox or google drive

Comment: ok will do that and update you